# Check if value in dataframe is more likely increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to check if the value inside is most likely to increase, decrease or constant. My code below checks if the value is strictly increasing, but i'm fine when 80% of the values are increasing/ decreasing. It is not important if the last values are higher

**Example_1**
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10])

**Output_1**
*df is increasing*

**Example_2**
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,5,5,7,8,9,5])

**Output_2**
*df is more or less constant, because more then 2 values are not increasing*

**Example_3**
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,5])

**Output_3**
*df is increasing, because 7 out of 9 values increase*

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10])
diff = df[0] - df[0].shift(1)
increasing = (diff <= 0).sum() == 0
if increasing :
    print ("increasing")
    
decreasing = (diff >= 0).sum() == 0
if decreasing :
    print("decreasing")
    
if increasing == False and decreasing == False:
    print("more or less constant")
```

Comment: what do you mean by *is most likely to increase*? do you just want to see whether each sequential number, is higher/lower/equal based on it's previous value (row-wise) ?

Comment: Could you please provide more examples with the expected output for different kind of sequences, so as to better clarify what you mean?

Comment: I did an update ;) hope it will help to understand me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, a series is increasing/decreasing if more than 80% of the differences between consecutive values are strictly increasing/decreasing.

You should achieve this with a slight modification of your code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10])
diff = df[0] - df[0].shift(1)
increasing = (diff <= 0).sum() <= 0.2 * len(df)
if increasing :
    print ("increasing")
    
decreasing = (diff >= 0).sum() <= 0.2 * len(df)
if decreasing :
    print("decreasing")
    
if increasing == False and decreasing == False:
    print("more or less constant")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be asking how to implement a linear regression in python?

Try:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

- if the slope is ~0 not increasing/decreasing.
- >0 increasing.
- <0 decreasing.